# How is WPF mouse event wired?

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

I am WPF newbie.  In a WPF sample code I am looking at, there is a mouse event handler as follows:

```
namespace Recipe_04_15
{
    public class DragCanvasControl : Canvas
    {
        ...
        static DragCanvasControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DragCanvasControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DragCanvasControl)));
        }
        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
...
```

What I don't understand is how the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method is wired to the mouse button down event.  The XAML code does not have events specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is already wired in the UIElement class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttondown.aspx
Since you inherit from the canvas you also inherit also from UIElement somewhere deeper.
*DragCanvasControl => Canvas => Panel => FrameworkElement => UIElement*

By overiding the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown from UIElement you get access to this event.

Comment: @Kris: Thank you, marked it as the answer.  I had not noticed the override keyword.  (WPF learning curve is steep!)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not in the XAML, it has to be attached in the code-behind. If it is not, the method will not be executed.

Be aware that you are actually looking for the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event and not some Click or MouseDown.

Comment: For Click fo instance ....
Inside [Windows1].xaml.cs you will see:

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

For this inside the [Windows1].g.i.cs you will see:

    #line 6 "..\..\Window1.xaml"
                this.button1.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.button1_Click);

Comment: [offtopic] would not it be nice to be able to format comments :P